# Google Earth Engine: Output too large when reducing resolution and exporting to Google Cloud

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, resampling, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-cloud

I'm calculating a bareground layer for Africa using Sentinel-2 at 10m resolution. I want to reduce the resolution to 1000m and then export it to Google Cloud Storage. However, this gives me an error of **"Reprojection output too large (23800x25600 pixels)."**

I would've accepted that what I'm trying to export is just too large, but the same code works perfectly fine for exporting a FIRMS fire data layer (initial resolution is 1000m resolution) and an ESA World Cover layer (initial resolution is 10m resolution), each resulting in about an 10Mb file.

Is it possible that the steps to calculate the `bareground` does something that makes the output too large? These steps are shared at the bottom.

**Exporting `bareground`**

```py
bareground_resampled = bareground.reproject(project_proj, None, 10).reduceResolution(
      reducer = ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
      maxPixels=10000
      ).reproject(project_proj, None, 1000)

task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(
    image=bareground_resampled.toDouble(),
    bucket='my_bucket',
    region=africa,
    fileNamePrefix='bareground_resampled',
    description='bareground_resampled',
    )
task.start()
```

The above results in **"Reprojection output too large (23800x25600 pixels)"**. Do you have any idea?

---

**How I calculated `bareground`**

1. First find the wettest month for each area in Africa.

```py
climate = ee.ImageCollection('WORLDCLIM/V1/MONTHLY').select('prec')


def add_month(image):
  month = ee.Number(image.get('month'))
  month_img = ee.Image.constant(month).toInt()
  new_image = image.addBands(month_img)
  return new_image

wettest_month = climate.map(add_month).reduce(ee.Reducer.max(2)).rename(['rain','month']).select('month')

def mask_wettest_month(month):
  month_mask = wettest_month.eq(ee.Number(month)).selfMask()
  month_mask = month_mask.set('month_property', ee.Number(month))
  return month_mask

month_list = ee.List.sequence(1, 12)
month_images = ee.ImageCollection(month_list.map(mask_wettest_month))
```

2. Then, find the corresponding Sentinel-2 image for the three months after the wettest month and calculate its NDVI. Here, I use [this code](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless) to mask Sentinel-2 clouds with `get_s2_sr_cld_col()`.

```py
def get_ndvi_for_month(image):
  start_date = ee.String('2021-').cat(ee.Number(image.get('month_property')).format('%02d')).cat('-01')
  date_filter = ee.Filter.date(ee.Date(start_date), ee.Date(start_date).advance(4, 'month'))

  sentinel = get_s2_sr_cld_col(datefilter).filterBounds(africa).map(add_cld_shdw_mask).map(apply_cld_shdw_mask).median()

  ndvi = sentinel.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).updateMask(image)

  return ndvi

ndvi_for_wettest_month = month_images.map(get_ndvi_for_month).sum()
```

3. Then, using a threshold formula with the annual rainfall as input for each pixel, identify bareground.

```py
annual_rainfall = ee.ImageCollection('WORLDCLIM/V1/MONTHLY').select('prec').sum()

threshold = annual_rainfall.expression(
    'log10(PREC)**0.5-1.45', {
      'PREC': annual_rainfall.select('prec')
})

bareground = ndvi_for_wettest_month.updateMask(ndvi_for_wettest_month.lt(threshold))
bareground = bareground.unmask()
```

Comment: Have you considered to increase `maxPixels=10000`?

Comment: Yes thanks, it doesn't help changing in the reduceResolution as I'd argue you don't need more pixels to resample from 10m to 1000m as there are only 10000 10m pixels in one 1000m pixel, if my math is correct.